# Appcelerator Titanium: Ti.include causes error "Object false has no method 'replace'" in Liveview

Tags: replace, include, titanium, appcelerator, liveview

I found that when launching an [Alloy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy) project in [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/) with Liveview enabled i got the error "Object false has no method 'replace'" caused by this line in the controller:

```
Ti.include("/common/Globals.js");
```

I don't see any error if i launch the same project with Liveview disabled.
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti.include is deprecated, and will never work in LiveView mode.

You should use require instead:

```
var yourName = require('your_file');
```

your_file.js

```
exports.myProperty = 'hi';
```

yourName.myProperty will return 'hi'

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium